# Getting an invalid token error while trying to make a post request

Tags: node.js, express

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const { isProduction } = require('../../config/keys');

if (!isProduction) {
    router.get("/restore", (req, res) => {
    const csrfToken = req.csrfToken();
    res.status(200).json({
        'CSRF-Token': csrfToken
    });
});
}

module.exports = router;
```

I was expecting a status of 200 ok but got 403 error of `invalid csrf token`. The token is generating fine and I can't figure out a way to solve this.

Comment: Hm, I am not sure your question title matches the code you are showing here. What I see here is a snippet of a GET endpoint being defined here which I guess is supposed to send the token back as json? Could you elaborate on what you are trying to do here?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.